# C forcing function execution in thread from other thread

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm using 2 different asynchronous event libraries. One in the main thread and one in the created thread. I want to call a function from the main thread in the created thread, but that fails because the asynchronous event library in the created thread never returns. Unfortunately I have to use this other asynchronous event library because it is part of the library that I'm using to achieve that functionality.

My code is (very simplified) as follows:

```
voic bla_x()
{
    //this function is called when someone io stuff is done
    //is actually called from within x_io_lib_loop_forever()
    main_io_lib_call_func_in_main(callback_func_main_process);
}

void init_x()
{
    //setup things
    x_io_lib_loop_forever();
}

void callback_func_main_process()
{
    main_io_lib_call_func_in_threadX(func_x);
}

void start_threadX()
{
    main_io_lib_register_handler(init_x);
    main_io_lib_register_handler(func_x);
    main_io_lib_loop_forever();
}

int main()
{
pthread_create(start_thread());
main_io_lib_call_func_in_thread(init_x);
main_io_lib_loop_forever();
}
```

The problem is as follows: I'm using two different event libraries (here called main_io and x_io). I'm using main_io to create a thread (pthread wrapper) and then to execute `init_x()` in the created thread. This works fine. The created thread then does some initialization and does it's io stuff using a different framework (`x_io_lib_loop_forever())`. When everything is setup in the created thread, `bla_x()` is called, which calls a function in the main process, which in turn wants to call a function in the created thread (`func_x()`).

This is where it goes wrong as `x_io_lib_loop_forever()` never returns, `func_x()` never gets executed in the created thread.

I'm thus looking for a way to kinda pause `x_io_lib_loop_forever()` and execute `func_x()` in that thread. Does anybody have any idea how to do that, or some better design ideas?

Comment: Which function do you mean by `this function`?

Comment: I would run both event loops in dedicated threads. Each event loop should only push eventts/callbacks/whatever to a queue. The main thread should only fetch items from the queue and process them.

Comment: @Armali , what do you mean with `this function` ? I gave all my functions names? Do you refer to the comment? That case it is `bla_x()`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I can't control the "inner workings" or how it is setup of the second thread unfortunately.

Comment: Does your x_io library allow you to define new event types and handlers?  If so just create an event type that wraps the function to be called (using `std::function` for example) and provide a handler.  From `main`, you can then just post a suitably constructed event.

Comment: @G.M. the only thing I can do is register a FD and a handler function. That could then poll the main thread to see if any event is happening, but that is an ugly solution and not really a good design solution as it keeps on polling continuously.

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly is a problem there. The second library should let you run your own code at some point, no? At that point insert an item in the queue and return.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI problem is the polling loop `x_io_lib_loop_forever` in the thread never returns. Meaning the `main_io_loop_forever` function (running in the thread) is never able to call `fun_x()` as the previous function that it called (`init_x()`) never returns.

Comment: Why would you need `x_io_lib_loop_forever` to return? You need it to call your code. At any rate I think it is counterproductive to discuss these imaginary libraries with their imaginary capabilities and shortcomings. Tell us what real life libraries you use, perhaps somebody will be able to come up with a real life way to use them together. I cannot do the same with library X because, well, as described it cannot be used in any way at all.

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to take a different approach and see if I could hack something in, that meant implementing part of main_io logic in the started thread. To be precisely, main_io uses a pipe to communicate events. By taking the fd (read part of the pipe) from main_io, and adding that fd to the listening part in the started thread, I was able to get an alert and get things running.